# По api получен zip-файл. Как его обработать? Php

Tags: php, api, zip

По api нужно получить данные, и они приходят в архиве. На скрине видно, что в ответе отображаются кракозябры. Если нажать на "Save response", то архив корректно сохраняется.

Как кодом сохранить этот архив в php? Спасибо.
[image: content-type: application/zip]
[image: content-type: application/zip]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить данные запросом на указанный API (curl, Guzzle, любой другой вариант), сохранить в переменную `$content`, сохранить как файл с помощью `file_put_contents('путь/архив.zip', $content)`

Answer (score -1):

Я для скачивания в браузере использую такой трюк:
На сервере:

```
echo '<a id="download_xls" href="'.$arResult['FILE']['SRC'].'" download="'.$arResult['FILE']['ORIGINAL_NAME'].'"></a>';
```

На клиенте:

```
$.ajax({
    url,
    method: 'POST',
    data,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#downloaded-files').html(data);
        $('#downloaded-files a').each(function () {
            this.click();
        })
    }
});
```